# How do you search within XML tags in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle11g

I'm using SQL Developer (Oracle 11g) to query a table that contains an XML field that has the following structure:

```
<Affordability>
<Data>
<Run RunNo="1" ChosenResult="N">
<Field1>xxx</Field1>
<Field2>xxx</Field2>
<Field3>xxx</Field3>
</Run>
<Run RunNo="2" ChosenResult="Y">
<Field1>xxx</Field1>
<Field2>xxx</Field2>
<Field3>xxx</Field3>
</Run>
<Run RunNo="3" ChosenResult="N">
<Field1>xxx</Field1>
<Field2>xxx</Field2>
<Field3>xxx</Field3>
</Run>
</Data>
</Affordability>
```

I'd like to be able to retrieve Field1, Field2 and Field3 from the Run that was the chosen result (ChosenResult = "Y").

So far I have a basic XMLTABLE query:

```
SELECT xt.*
FROM table t,
          XMLTABLE('/Affordability/Data/Run'
            PASSING t.xml_data
            COLUMNS
              Field1   VARCHAR2(20)  PATH 'Field1'
              Field2   VARCHAR2(20)  PATH 'Field2'
              Field3   VARCHAR2(20)  PATH 'Field3'
            ) xt
```

But I can't work out how to search the  tags to get ChosenResult = "Y".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the values of the attributes then use `@`:

```sql
SELECT xt.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         '/Affordability/Data/Run'
         PASSING t.xml_data
         COLUMNS
           Field1       VARCHAR2(20)  PATH 'Field1',
           Field2       VARCHAR2(20)  PATH 'Field2',
           Field3       VARCHAR2(20)  PATH 'Field3',
           RunNo        NUMBER(3,0)   PATH '@RunNo',
           ChosenResult CHAR(1)       PATH '@ChosenResult'
       ) xt
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( xml_data ) AS
SELECT XMLTYPE('<Affordability>
<Data>
<Run RunNo="1" ChosenResult="N">
<Field1>xxx</Field1>
<Field2>xxx</Field2>
<Field3>xxx</Field3>
</Run>
<Run RunNo="2" ChosenResult="Y">
<Field1>xxx</Field1>
<Field2>xxx</Field2>
<Field3>xxx</Field3>
</Run>
<Run RunNo="3" ChosenResult="N">
<Field1>xxx</Field1>
<Field2>xxx</Field2>
<Field3>xxx</Field3>
</Run>
</Data>
</Affordability>') FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | FIELD1 | FIELD2 | FIELD3 | RUNNO | CHOSENRESULT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | xxx | xxx | xxx | 1 | N |
> | xxx | xxx | xxx | 2 | Y |
> | xxx | xxx | xxx | 3 | N |

---

If you only want the `ChosenResult="Y"` row then you could filter by adding:

```sql
WHERE xt.chosenresult = 'Y'
```

to the above query but you probably want to do it in the XPath:

```sql
SELECT xt.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         '/Affordability/Data/Run[@ChosenResult="Y"]'
         PASSING t.xml_data
         COLUMNS
           Field1       VARCHAR2(20)  PATH 'Field1',
           Field2       VARCHAR2(20)  PATH 'Field2',
           Field3       VARCHAR2(20)  PATH 'Field3',
           RunNo        NUMBER(3,0)   PATH '@RunNo',
           ChosenResult CHAR(1)       PATH '@ChosenResult'
       ) xt
```

Which outputs:

> | FIELD1 | FIELD2 | FIELD3 | RUNNO | CHOSENRESULT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | xxx | xxx | xxx | 2 | Y |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=40011c9c65bfc6a1fbebe19ac31fadae)*

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! So I can research this topic further, what are the blue key words within the <Run> tag called (i.e. RunNo, ChosenResult)?

Comment: @jakrooster As I mentioned in the answer, they are "attributes". They are defined in the XML specification [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-attr).